# Map cookies with specific prefix to headers in Nginx

Tags: http, nginx

Given the following cookie request header:

```
Cookie: foo_bar=123;foo_baz=456;foo_foo=789
```

Is it possible to forward the following headers to origin, by checking for the presence of the `foo_` cookie prefix?

```
bar: 123
baz: 456
foo: 789
```

Is it possible to combine map with some sort of array output?

```
map $http_cookie $headers {
  default                                  "";
  "~*foo_(?<key>.*)=(?<token>[^;]+)"       "$key $token"; # NOT FUNCTIONAL - Is there any way to get this working?
}
```

Comment: How are you using `$headers`?

Comment: That's part of the question actually: I would like the map to output an array of headers that I can then push to origin

Comment: So you want to split the cookie into a number of headers. I think you will need to use a language add-on like Perl or Lua to accomplish this.

Comment: Makes sense, you can add this as an answer